# Show that $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}{6n^3 + 30 \over n^3+n^2 + n +1} = 6$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}{\dfrac{6n^3 + 30}{n^3+n^2 + n + 1}} = 6$ using only the definition of convergence.

Please, I need to see how this is done step by step. This isn't homework, but I always get tripped up on this type of problem and need to see how it's done properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{6n^3 + 30}{n^3 + n^2 + n + 1} - 6 = \frac{-6n^2 - 6n + 24}{n^3 + n^2 + n + 1}$$

Informally, this tends to $0$ since the degree on top is smaller.

We can also say that

$$\left|\frac{-6n^2 - 6n + 24}{n^3 + n^2 + n + 1}\right| \le \frac{6n^2 + 6n^2 + 24n^2}{n^3 + n^2 + n + 1} \le \frac{36n^2}{n^3} = \frac{36}{n}$$

So given $\epsilon > 0$, set $N = \frac{36}{\epsilon}$. Then $n \ge N$ implies that

$$\left|\frac{-6n^2 - 6n + 24}{n^3 + n^2 + n + 1}\right| < \epsilon$$

and the limit is $6$.

Comment: In the middle expression of the middle line take off that $\;n^2\;$ in the last summand of the numerator.

Comment: This is the most intuitive method to me, thank you. I see why you would have the additional $n^2$ that the other answerer recommends you remove. But I like it, I trust it. I'm comfortable with it.

Comment: Wait a second, how exactly does $n\geq N$ imply $\left|\frac{-6n^2 - 6n + 24}{n^3 + n^2 + n + 1}\right| < \epsilon$?? Please explain precisely.

Answer (score 6):

Hints:

$$\left|\frac{6n^3+30}{n^3+n^2+n+1}-6\right|=\left|\frac{-6n^2-6n+24}{n^3+6n^2+n+1}\right|\le\frac{6n^2+6n+24}{n^3}\le\frac{18}n$$

Now, what $\,n\,$ do you have to choose so that $\;\frac{18}n<\epsilon\;$ , no matter what $\;\epsilon >0\;$ was chosen?

Comment: Tell that to the people who upvoted you instantly also :-)

Comment: Ah,. those people "felt" the inside shine of wisdom...;)

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I made a typo, it was supposed to be a -1 in the denominator, not a +1. I don't know if it really matters, though, since this is just a practice problem.

Comment: It **really** doesn't matter at all, @JohanLiebert

Comment: How do you know $\frac{6n^2+6n+24}{n^3}\le\frac{18}n$? Was there some invisible algebra done there?

Comment: Well, not that visible certainly: $$6n^2+6n+24\le 6n^2+6n^2+6n^2=18n^2\iff 2n^2\ge n+4\iff 2n^2-n-4\ge 0$$ and solving this quadratic inequality you get that it must be  $$n\ge \frac{1+\sqrt{33}}4\cong 3.3\ldots$$